# Eve online api get volume of object

Tags: api-eveonline

Does anyone know what to query in the eve api to get the size (volume) in cubic meters m3 for an object in Eve online?

I can get all the other stuff so it's not about accessing the servers. It's finding this part of the item data.

For instance this will give the info on Tritanium.

```
https://public-crest.eveonline.com/types/34/
```

But it will not give the m3 size of the object which is crucial.

Answer (score 2):

With the new ESI API, it is possible to get an item's volume from the JSON response.
To get the Tritanium item details, GET request must be made like the following:

```
https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/universe/types/34/?language=en-us&datasource=tranquility
```

The resulting JSON response will have the volume information among other things:

```json
{
  "type_id": 34,
  "name": "Tritanium",
  "description": "...",
  "published": true,
  "group_id": 18,
  "radius": 1.0,
  "volume": 0.01,
  "icon_id": 22,
  "capacity": 0.0,
  "portion_size": 1,
  "mass": 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does.
It's called the volume of the item.
In this case 1 tritanium is 0.01m3